# How to pipe a group of files through a .exe using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am currently using a .exe named "vbadecompiler.exe" to process a group o ".xlsm" files. Those are to many to process manually therefore Powershell seems like the answer. My current attempt is the following:

```
dir *.xlsm | foreach-object {.\vbadecompiler.exe cmd/decompile /sXLfile:=$_ /sApplication:=Excel /sAppVersion:=Default /bOverBackup:=1 /bPreservDateTime:=0 /bLogActivity:=1 /sFilePassword:=""}
```

But it only runs through the first file, there are 100+ files to be processed. I can't find how to make it run through everything. How should it be done?

PD: Just found out there is a simpler way to do this using VBA:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956651/execute-a-command-in-command-prompt-using-excel-vba

Comment: Do you need the period at the end of `/sXLfile:=$_.` ?

Comment: In the foereach-object cmdlet the $_. represents the object. That's why it's there.

Comment: You only need the dot if you are accessing a member of the object (e.g. `$_.FullName`). With no member, it should just be `$_`. In this case, if the file was 'foo.xlsm', `/sXLfile:=$_.` will be interpreted as: `/sXLfile:=foo.xlsm .` (note the space and dot after the file name)

Comment: Removed the dot but i continue to have the same problem; it's only running once. I guess i should create several instances of the .exe but whether it doesn't allow or a don't know how.

Comment: Is vbadecompiler.exe a console application that runs in the same window as powershell, or something else?

Comment: have you tried waiting for execution to return? (start-process -wait iirc)

Comment: In response to Ryant: No, it's not a console application. In response to horatio: I will right away(Addendum: It didn't work; or i don't know how to write it in the script).

Comment: @AndresPerez I was thinking the same as @horatio if it wasn't a console application. The command in the foreach ScriptBlock would be `Start-Process .\vbadecompiler.exe -Wait -ArgumentList cmd/decompile, /sXLfile:=$_, /sApplication:=Excel, /sAppVersion:=Default, /bOverBackup:=1, /bPreservDateTime:=0, /bLogActivity:=1, '/sFilePassword:=""'`